# boot_complete delay or location

Tags: android, broadcast, boot, bootcompleted

I would like to know if there is a way to delay the boot_complete broadcast without harming the boot stages? i.e. where in the AOSP code can I find the part where the intent is being broadcasted so I could run another code prior to sending it?

Another option is the code location where the bootanimation is being stoped...

Can anyone help?

Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look into [SystemServer.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/services/java/com/android/server/SystemServer.java). When boot is completed, [Zygote](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteInit.java) forks system server process, where all pre-boot initialization is made, and java services started. You can create your service and start it here.

**Edit:** `bootanimation` is started also as a `service` from [init.rc](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/android-4.1.2_r1/rootdir/init.rc) file, `line 422`.

Comment: Thank you for your help! Can you tell me how can I postpone the ending of the bootanimation? I need to run some code before the bootanimation ends and before the BOOT_COMPLETED is being broadcasted. Where can I insert my code?

Comment: add your code somewhere in SystemServer.initAndLoop() method, for ex. before ActivityManagerService.self().systemReady(...) or in the end of run() method inside ActivityManagerService.self().systemReady()

Comment: So lets say I'll place my code in the end of run() method inside ActivityManagerService.self().systemReady(), and lets say my code takes a while to be executed (1-2 minutes), will it make the bootanimation to continue running and won't broadcast the BOOT_COMPLETED untill my code will be finished?

Comment: you can sleep the Thread for tests and check boot_animation time. I never made this, but it should work. I used SystemServer for my own service start.

Comment: OK. and one last question: at this point in my code (end of run() method inside ActivityManagerService.self().systemReady), ALL system services are running, correct? If from my code I'll send an intent to a system service, It should react to it, right?

Comment: they should. you can check it easily, why don't you try? :)

Comment: Pemission issues... I'll check it soon. Thanx!